# Corrupt 'current' file in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

there's a repo on a server which is used for documents. I'm on win10 and I mapped that "network share" to P. So we can find the repo at:

```
P:/foo/bar/
```

if I do

```
svn co file:///P:/foo/bar/
```

or

```
svn svn+ssh user@server.com/path/fo/repo
```

I get

```
svn: E160004: Corrupt 'current' file
```

Also, if I try to svnadmin in the repos dir, I get the same error. This error arised suddendly.

Now, I'm the only one who uses console, all other use TortoiseSVN. On my Working PC, which I didn't set up (win 7), the checkout using TortoiseSVN works but it doesn't using the console. It also works for everyone else.

So, I do have this corrupt file error but people are still able to checkout. I'm an absolute noob when it comes to svn, since I only use git.

Can someone tell me what I can do?

Comment: If it works with TortoiseSVN, but not with the command line tools, I'd start by checking the version numbers. Maybe the `current` file is newer than your client, but not newer than TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running svnadmin recover?  My recollection is that on more recent versions of SVN it will fix the current file.

The file itself is pretty simple. It just contains the revision number of the HEAD revision of the repository.  So if you know what that is, in the worst case you can set the value with a text editor that does not add CRLF line ending to end of the file.

I would first try svnadmin recover.  If that does not work, I would move the current file to a temp folder and try svnadmin recover again.  If that does not work, then edit the file in an editor like Notepad++ that will let you keep the LF line-ending.